# Getting permissions for using instagram api

Tags: api, instagram

I have made an android application that enables advertisers to count the posts each one of their followers/followings have liked. this way they'll be able to understand which one of them is more active and which one is not, I also have added another feature for sending like requests to the followers/followings by leaving a like on their most recent post and leaving a comment that tells them "I liked your posts come and like my posts".
I registered a submission and explained everything as they wanted, but they declined my submission :(
Now my question is How should I explain it for them or WHAT CHANGES should I apply to my application so they approve it.

This is their answer:

> General issues:
>
> Invalid Use Case: The use case described in your submission notes,
>   screencast and website is not a valid use case. If you are trying to
>   build analytics for personal use or one-off projects, note that we do
>   not support one-off and single use projects. We recommend that you use
>   a third-party platform that powers this use case. If you are building
>   a platform for this use case, we will only approve one client ID for
>   all your integrations. For more information, please see:
>   https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/ Policy Violation ("Like",
>   "Follow", "Comment" Exchange Program): Your app shouldn't participate,
>   enable or promote any “like”, “share”, “comment” or “follower”
>   exchange programs. In working to build a high quality platform
>   experience, we ask that you comply with our Platform Policy
>   (http://wwww.instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/).

I have to say my application is not a ONE-OFF application, as the number of liked posts vary from time to time, so the user will check this application almost every day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I also have added another feature for sending like requests to the
>   followers/followings by leaving a like on their most recent post and
>   leaving a comment that tells them "I liked your posts come and like my
>   posts".

This is against the API policy:

> Your app shouldn't participate, enable or promote any “like”, “share”,
>   “comment” or “follower” exchange programs.

Comment: Now the question is If our app shouldn't like/comment any posts from the user side, so why does Instagram provide like/comment post APIs?? @krisrak